# How to automate if possible

Tags: java

I am trying to print out all my elements of the array and add themselves to their index as I already figured. I don't know how to automate it. It works, but it can be better.

```
public class homeworkArrays 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] myArray = {6, 7, 2, 1, 10, 34};
        int blank = addByIndex(myArray);
    }

    public static int addByIndex(int[] myArray) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)   
        {   
            System.out.println(i + " - " + myArray[i]); 

        }

            myArray[0] = myArray[0] + myArray[0];
            System.out.println("0 is now " + myArray[0]);
            myArray[1] = myArray[1] + myArray[1];
            System.out.println("1 is now " + myArray[1]);
            myArray[2] = myArray[2] + myArray[2];
            System.out.println("2 is now " + myArray[2]);
            myArray[3] = myArray[3] + myArray[3];
            System.out.println("3 is now " + myArray[3]);
            myArray[4] = myArray[4] + myArray[4];
            System.out.println("4 is now " + myArray[4]);
            myArray[5] = myArray[5] + myArray[5];
            System.out.println("5 is now " + myArray[5]);


    int i = 0;
    return myArray[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered a simple for-loop?

Comment: You say "add themselves to their index" yet you double all the values? According to the input, the output should be: 6, 8, 4, 4, 14, 39??

Comment: Deco, your correct on the output. That is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)   
{   
    System.out.println(i + " - " + myArray[i]); 
    myArray[i] = myArray[i] * 2;
    System.out.println(i + " after multiplication - " + myArray[i]); 
}
```

What's not that clear is that part:

```
int i = 0;
return myArray[i];
```

What do you try to achieve in that?

Comment: ...I'll just swap the two statements in the loop around. I seems like "bad boy" does the calculation first and then the print out.

Comment: I was experimenting with outputting my integers from the array for proof it was working. I actually don't need it.

Comment: Your solution works fine and so does the myArray[i] += myArray[i]; You guys must be coding all the time to be able to throw ideas out there so easily. I spent half the day until I gave in and asked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @badboy - we all tackled such problem when we started :)

Answer (score 2):

binyamin got it right but i would suggest

```
myArray[i] += myArray[i];
```

as multiplication of ints has more overhead than simple addition.

Comment: just an after thought nothing of great consequence.. i know!! :p

Comment: @WickeD - it might be faster, might be shorter to write, I just thought that "multiply the value" sound more precise than "adding the value to itself"

Comment: @binyamin: i know and like i said, nothing of great consequence!!

Comment: Well you could also do myArray[i] <<= 2 in such a case

Comment: @Jerome - and that will be wrong... should be `<<=1` :-P I prefer to be clear, and bit shifting instead of arithmetic operations is just not that clear. The compiler will optimize such an operation anyway.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Oh yes you're right, wrong typing

Comment: I am still learning and I knew I could improve with expert input from stack overflow. Thanks!

Comment: @Jerome - I just tried to demonstrate why I prefer arithmetics.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if i got your question  right but try this.....

```
public static int addByIndex(int[] myArray) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)   
    {   
        System.out.println(i + " - " + myArray[i]);
        myArray[i] += myArray[i];
        System.out.println(i " is now " + myArray[i]);
    } 
    int i = 0;
    return myArray[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are doubling the values, and the current answers are also doubling the values too. Your question says "add themselves to their index", which means if you have number `4` in array index `2` your output should be `6`.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] += i;
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
```

The above code will take each element in the array and add the current index to it - then print the value.

Comment: i think he meant doubling the values only just made some mistake in the description part..